# Matlab to Python Conversion for symmetry and repmat

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

**How can I make symmetry of a function in Python?**

I have a filter and I need to make symmetry of that.

In MATLAB the command is

```
filt = [filt , filt(end-1:-1:2)];
```

Also I need to know how to use repmat in python.
 This is the step of MATLAB that I want to convert to Python.

```
filt = repmat(filt',[1 1024]);
```

Comment: What does the MATLAB step do? What is the input and the expected output? Any sample data?

Comment: Expected shape of filt after repmat should be (2048,1024). And it should be a ramp filter.